# Does resizing/moving partitions in gparted delete files on the drive?

Tags: partitioning, gparted

Does resize/move in gparted delet files in drive? I have only one partition and I need to divide it.

[image: gparted application showing my disk]

Comment: You are not showing a lot of data. The more data you have the longer it can take and any interruption will corrupt your data. So have good backups. Your little key icons show you are using gparted on your working system. You can only edit unmounted partition so need to boot Ubuntu live installer in live mode and use gparted  or create gparted flash drive using gparted live ISO to change partitions.

Comment: See “Step 0” of [the top answer](/a/18525/175814) to the linked question. It's always a good idea to back up your data, especially before any operation that changes file system geometry. Data without back-ups is by definition unimportant.

Answer (score 0):

Resize & moving a partition can be two different things.

Expanding a Partition size should not delete any Data. However, reducing the size of a Partition could if it's smaller than the Data, power issues. I am assuming the your HD is solid.
However, there's no room for error. So, best would be to backup your Data & unmount the partition (restrictions) use  GParted and do your thing.

That's the beauty of Linux...you learn from research & playing around with your machine...that way you remember it forever

Comment: gparted won't let you: try on a USB stick.  **:P ;-)**